# Custom UIButton with UIImageView doesn't work fine on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

My problem is I have a Custom button and ImageView to which I added the Image.I made this imageView to the custom button as a subview.when Im running it in simulator it workin fine,but when Im runnig it in Device it was not displaying the image in the button.

I written the code as:

In cellForRowtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MasterViewIdentifier"];
 if (cell == nil) 
 {

  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"MasterViewIdentifier"] autorelease];
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

  UIView* elementView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,170,320,280)];
  elementView.tag = 0;
  elementView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:elementView];
  [elementView release];

 }
 UIView* elementView  = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:0];
 elementView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 for(UIView* subView in elementView.subviews)
 {
  [subView removeFromSuperview];
 }
         if(indexPath.section == 8)
   {
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_Star.png"];
            MyCustomButton *button1 = [[MyCustomButton alloc]initWithRating:1];  
  [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(159, 15, 25, 20)];
  [button1 setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
  [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [button1 addSubview:imageView];
  [elementView addSubview:button1];
  [button1 release];
  [imageView release];
         }
return cell;
}
```

and in my buttonAction:

```
-(void)buttonAction:(MyCustomButton*)sender
{
 rating = [sender ratingValue];
 event.eventRatings = rating;
 [tableView reloadData];

}
```

and i MyCustomButton class:
i have a method as

```
-(MyCustomButton*) initWithRating:(NSInteger)aRatingValue
{
 if (self = [super init])
 {
  self.ratingValue = aRatingValue;
 }
 return self;
}
```

pls help guys from dis problem.

Thank you,
Monish.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load image named "yellow_Star.png" - check if it actually named so (with the same characters case). File system on iPhone is case sensitive and on Mac OS is not - so it is often causes such problems and file names is the first thing to look at.

**Edit:** You can also try to check if the image is present in the application bundle - may be it was removed from copy resources build step by chance, that is your image must be in a "Copy Bundle Resources" build step for your build target. If it is absent you can just drag and drop your image there.

Comment: Yes I had given the same name with Case sensitive only.Even though it was not displaying the image in button.

Comment: You can also try to check if the image is present in the application bundle - may be it was removed from copy resources build step by chance

Comment: Actually the Images are present in the application folder it was not present in the application bundle.and I get those images from the application folder to the Resources folder in the XCode.